# Endereço de host para o Clickonce

Tags: visual-studio-2012, atualização

Preciso passar um endereço de host no padrão http://www.meusite.org.br/pasta como o local onde fica disponibilizada a atualização em "Update Location" que está dentro de "Updates" na Guia "Publish" das propriedades do projeto.

Quando passo o endereço de rede no padrão X:\meusite.org.br\pasta encontro a atualização e executo sem problemas mas quando coloco como no primeiro exemplo ele não encontra nada e não dá nenhuma mensagem de erro ou alerta.

O motivo disso é que preciso que o cliente encontre a atualização independente de estar na rede ou fora dela.

Answer (score 1):

para solucionar esse problema precisei colocar em *Instalation folder URL* o endereço de rede e em *Update Location* dentro de *Upddates* coloquei o endereço de host.